# Captive Build Flash Builder 4.6 Problems

Tags: apache-flex, air, adobe, flash-builder

I have a weird problem with Flex and Flash Builder 4.6 captive build.

I'm doing an Windows AIR App, and it all works fine, both as an AIR app and form the IDE. However when I make it into a Captive build, its like anything that references Capabilities, just doesn't get compiled in.

No errors or anything. Thus all my window centre, docking functionality just doesn't exist.

Even this line, in an attempt to debug, doesn't fire

```
mx.controls.Alert.show(Capabilities.screenResolutionX.toString());
```

If I do an Alert.show('here') on the same line, which is in the init function called from creationComplete it shows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked out what is going on, however I don't understand it. I'll post this as the answer because it is the answer, but if someone wants to post the answer as why, I'll gladly accept their answer.

This is the first bit of code in the init method

```
// Force Start Program on login.
if (!Capabilities.isDebugger)
{
    NativeApplication.nativeApplication.startAtLogin = true;
}
```

Nothing else after this code executes, which makes me think that its getting an error and dropping out of the method. If I remove this code, all is well again. But why?

Comment: I'm thinking that this code doesn't make sense in a Captive build as there is no AIR to control its startup.

Comment: As @Dale states, caprive runtime builds have some limitations.

This article talks about creating your own custom installer: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/air3-install-and-deployment-options.html#articlecontentAdobe_numberedheader_0

I think you will have to look into using a native extension in order to get your application to start at login.

Comment: All I needed to do was using the installer, I use Advanced Installer put it into the startup folder.